# Coffeescript, array length undefined

Tags: arrays, coffeescript

Could anyone explain me why the length is always null?

```
jsCountries = 
  0:
    country: "Brazil"
    photo:  "source.png"


alert jsCountries.length
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I dont know exactly what you want to do. If you want to use your code than the access would be

```
Object.keys(jsCountries).length
```

If however your intention is to create an array of country objects than I would suggest to initialize your jsCountries var differently

```
jsCountries = [
   {country: "Brazil", photo:  "source.png"},
   {country: "Argentina", photo:  "aregentina_source.png"},
   ...
]
```

Then of the following will work

```
jsCountries.length
```

In anyway I would strongly suggest not to use numeric keys for an object even thou its possible.

Comment: Thank you for your help. i've used finally: jsCountries = [ { country: "Albania", photo:  "svg.png" } ]

Answer (score 6):

You are declaring an object, with the property `0` set, not an Array.

You want:

```
jsCountries = [
  country: "Brazil"
  photo:  "source.png"
]

alert jsCountries.length
```